# insert table with onclick JS function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want a onclick button that when you press it, it shows up a pre-compilated table.
I've tried to use the table as a text or a paragraph in teh script and obviusly it did'nt work. I can't figure out how to do it. can you help me?

Comment: You should add any pertinent code along with your question.

Comment: Just put the table in the HTML with `display: none`  style. When the button is pressed, change it to `display: block` and it will show.

Comment: Please add code to your question to provide context

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to add the table with a 'hide' class, like:

```
<button id='toggleTable'>
  show/hide table
</button>
<table class='hide' id='tableTarget'>
...
</table>
```

The js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document
    .querySelector('#toggleTable')
    .addEventListener(
      'click', 
      () => {
        document
          .querySelector('#tableTarget')
          .classList
          .toggle('hide')
      },
      false
    )
  },
  false
)
```

the css:

```
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

if you use any frontend framework should be easier. But this is with plain html/js/css. And IE9 is not supported with this solution. If you need it, you have to change a little bit the js code.

Good Luck!